# Increment value of array object by using values of another array's objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I'm trying to figure out how to get cumulative values from a data table that a user enters values in. I've stored all of the data into an array representing the *raw data*, and I am trying to increment an array which is a copy of the array representing the raw data in order to obtain the cumulative data for the graph. I am trying to do this by incrementing each value object of the array to the values of each index of the raw data array up to the current index. I'm doing this through a loop, but it doesn't seem to be working. My code for the function is here:

```
function generateChartData() {
    var rawData = [];
    var chartData = [];
    jQuery('.data-row').each(function () {
        var date = jQuery(this).find('.data-category').val();
        var value = jQuery(this).find('.data-value').val();
        var value2 = jQuery(this).find('.data-value2').val();
        if (date != '') {
            rawData.push({
                date: date,
                value: value,
                value2: value2

            });
        }
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++)
    {
        chartData[date][i] = rawData[date][i];
        for(var j = i; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            chartData[i][value]+=rawData[j][value];
            chartData[i][value]+=rawData[j][value2];
        }
    }

    return chartData;
}
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skhaksari/tsox1p8x/)

Comment: You're not setting `date` in the `for` loop. And since there's no `chartData[date]`, you can't set `chartData[date][i]`.

Comment: Shouldn't `rawData[date][i]` be `rawData[i].date`? You seem to be confused about array and objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not properly accessing array and object elements. And you can just use a simple variable to hold the running total.

```
var valueSum = 0;
var value2Sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
    rd = rawData[i];
    valueSum += rd.value;
    value2Sum += rd.value2;
    chartData.push({
        date: rd.date,
        value: valueSum,
        value2: value2Sum
    });
}
```